# Turning Navigation Silverlight into out-of-browser application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have created Silverlight application using Navigation template. I wanted to turn it into out-of-browser application. But on the Debug tab, out-of-browser application radio-box is not enabled. Why it is so and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to the fact that its a Navigation application.  It works well in oob.

Is it with VS2008 or 2010?

Try re-creating a new project (using Navigation Template) to see if the radio button is enabled (in my case it is with vs2010).  If it works on that new project, I suggest you transfer all your sources files on that new project.

Add a screenshot of your debug tab.